# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #4](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/4) on Aviation has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Ralph J]

[image: DeltaLima]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following users, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Federico]

[image: fooot]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5975809369047040).

Answer (score 13):

Thank you all for your entrusting the moderator role to me. I hope not to disappoint you all too often :-)

Congratulations to Ralph J, I am looking forward to working together with you, Jamiec and Farhan in keeping our site at a high quality level and it's community healthy.

Thank you JJJ, Jpe61 and New Alexandria for volunteering for this position as well.

Comment: I'm delighted to see you're back D. The stack cannot be in better hands.

Comment: @mins Thank you. I have never been gone, still visiting here almost every day. But my level of participation will increase now back to where it was in the early days.

Answer (score 8):

Congrats Ralph J and DeltaLima! Those are big shoes to fill but I'm sure your extensive participation on Aviation will navigate you right through any communication hurdles along the way. Good luck! :D

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations! I'm confident you'll both be great mods! :)

Comment: Thank you Federico, I really appreciate you saying that. And thank for all you have done for this site over the last 5 years.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations, our future is in good hands!

And many thanks to Federico & Fooot!